# Is there an equation for the amount of ones in a binary number?

Tags: number-theory, summation, binary

We know that any natural number can be expressed as a binary number. Is there an equation or algorithm for the amount of ones in a binary number? I tried searching for this, but all I could find were computer codes to calculate it. I'm looking for an actual mathematical function. Is there one? If so, what is it? I believe this is also called the Hamming weight. Any help would be appreciated, even links or references. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by algorithm if not "computer code to calculate" the value?

Comment: "all I could find were computer codes to calculate it. I'm looking for an actual mathematical function"
A computer code can be a mathematical function.
You seem to assume that a mathematical function is a "formula" - it's not https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082718/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-and-a-formula

Comment: "I'm looking for an actual mathematical function. Is there one? "  Sure:  Let $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be defined as $f(n)=$ the number of $1$ digits in the binary representations of $n$.  ... That *IS* a well defined function.

Comment: See [OEIS A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120) sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Sum of the binary digits of a natural number $n$ is
$$n-\sum_{i=1}^\infty  \lfloor n/2^i\rfloor.$$

Note that this sum has at most $\log_2(n)$ nonzero summands.

I thought this formula should be all over the Web but could not find it. Here is the proof. Let $r(n)$ denotes the last binary digit of $n$. Then $r(n)=n-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. The sum of binary digits of $n$ is $$r(n)+r(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)+r(\lfloor n/4\rfloor)+... 
 $$
which implies the formula.

Answer (score 0):

For sequences like this, I suggest you try [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A000120).  You're likely to find something related to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively...

Let $a_n$ be the number of $1$s in the binary representation of $n$. Then $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and $a_n=1+a_{n-2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}}$.

For example, $$
\begin{align}
a_{23}&=1+a_{7}&a_{24}&=1+a_{8}\\
&=1+1+a_{3}&&=1+1+a_{0}\\
&=1+1+1+a_{1}&&=1+1+0\\
&=1+1+1+1
\end{align}
$$
This approach has speed roughly $c\cdot a_n$, where $c$ is how long it takes to compute $n-2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}$. An approach that sums after dividing by powers of $2$ has speed roughly $d\log_2(n)$, where $d$ is the time to compute a division by a power of $2$. I think in general the recursive approach is faster, but I am not offering a proof.